# Where the Logger info stored in Java?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

In this piece of code, where is the logged info stored(i.e. "Needed parameters: ")?

Is it in some file in my project?

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        logger.info("Needed parameters: ");
        logger.info("\t rootFolder (it will contain intermediate crawl data)");
        logger.info("\t numberOfCralwers (number of concurrent threads)");
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What slf4j implementation are you using? How did you configure your loggers?

Comment: I downloaded a program for testing. I did nothing configuration. I think it's a default implementation.

Comment: Look at [`SimpleLogger`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Where the Logger info stored in Java

Typically, it is written a file.  However, that depends on how you configure the underlying logger implementation.

Note that your example code is (most likely) an incorrect / inappropriate use of logging.  It appears to be writing error messages that the user needs to see; i.e. when they get the command line arguments wrong.  Error messages that are intended for the end user should be written to "standard error" (or possibly "standard output").  Generally speaking, the user doesn't know to look in a log file.

Comment: Does this statement "private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicCrawlerController.class);" specify the logging file location?

Comment: No.  That just creates a logger instance.  The logger configuration is typically a file, though it depends on what logger implementation you are using behing the slf4j facade.

Comment: If you are doing your development on any version of Windows, then you can use Mark Russinovitch's excellent Process Monitor tool which will give you the name and location of every file your application touches. The tool is available here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645